# How are memory registers used to hold different types?

Tags: assembly, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, cpu-registers

I have come under the impression that if a program reserves memory for a variable type **integer** (which is 8 bytes in size) the memory that is reserved will be 8 different registers that appear sequentially in memory.

My questions are as follows:

1. Assuming that answers will vary is my statement above a good generalization that each byte required by different types of variables equate out to that variable using 1 register in memory? (that is 1 byte  requires one register in memory)
2. If that is true how many bits does each register in memory hold? Or if I bought a 32-bit computer does that mean each register in memory holds 32 bits?
3. And if integer type needed 8 different registers for its size of 8 bytes what is contained in each different register?
4. Also I am trying to understand the idea of types. I know that if you have 32 bits to work with you could represent **unsigned integer** values from 0 to 4294967295. Yet if I stored the **unsigned integer** 4294967295 in a memory cell of 32-bits how would the CPU know that the binary representation within this memory cell needs to be decoded into the **unsigned integer** format? That is, is the memory set aside for a certain type specify that certain type or does a pointer specify the type or perhaps something completely different?

I am generally knowledgeable in the ideas of binary arithmetic, assembly language, references, pointers, and how variables and arrays are stored in the memory heap (so I'll understand any answers using these contexts). And I can program in C, C++, and Java. Thanks for any given help.

Comment: Where you're writing "memory register", it seems you actually mean "memory location", i.e. one byte of memory.  This not a register, certainly not [cpu-registers].  "Memory cell" comes closest to being the equivalent, but that often means exactly 1 bit, not a whole byte.

Answer (score 3):

1, 2, 3: don't refer to memory as registers; although I've seen that done before it is confusing. a 64-bit processor has 8-byte-wide registers and a 32-bit processor has 4-byte-wide registers, but when those registers are copied into RAM it's just bytes in memory. what part of an integer is stored in which byte depends on the endianness of the processor: a little-endian system will store the 1 bit in 0x1 in the first (lowest) address of the 8 bytes, and a big-endian system will store it in the last.

4: the CPU doesn't know nor care; "types" is a high-level-language construct, to a CPU everything is a number: "abcd" is a number as 0xf0f0f0f0 is a number. you have to give it instructions according to what you want it to do, e.g. for x86 use IDIV instead of DIV if you want it to treat the number as signed.

Answer (score 2):

Types are for the most part fiction for the benefit of the programming language.  To a processor bits is bits, they have no meaning other than sometimes briefly during the execution of a single instruction, losing their meaning when that instruction is over.

Dijkstra: “Computer science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes.”

You need tp specify the processor you are interested in your question, or are you interested in processors in general.  The common mix of processors today vary from ones with 8 bit registers to 64 bit or larger with 8 bit, 16, bit, 32 bit, 64 bit register based processors all being represented.

Also dont get confused about everything being in a register, some processors have lots of registers and many items in your high level code sit around in registers for a while, while other processors dont have a lot of registers and most of your variables live in ram not in registers.  It is more common than not that there will be some ram for your variables even if a register is holding that data for long periods of time.  Optimizers really mess with that balance though so it is hard to make general statements.

You say you know assembly language, take this assembly language pseudocode for example:

```
mov r1,#0x20000000
shl r2,r0,5
add r1,r2
ldr r0,[r1]
```

This resembles what you might see if you had an array of structs 32 bytes in size, and you wanted to get at the first element, say it was a single precision float.  And you wanted that float from the element number in the array held in the register r0, we dont care what that element number is, the code operates on whatever it is.

```
struct 
{
  float f;
  stuff...32 bits total
} mystruct[MYSTRUCTSIZE];
...
unsigned int i;
...
something=mystruct[i].f
...
```

The above assembly pseudocode computes the mystruct[i].f address and loads it from memory to be put into or used by the something code.

The bits 0x20000000 we might happen to know are some address in memory where this array of structs lives, but for now, for a mov instruction, it is just bits, an immediate value we are loading into a register.  Often the mov instruction does not affect flags so this has no signed or unsigned or any meaning at all to the cpu other than some bits going into a register.  Assume 32 bit registers and address space for this pseudo code

As mentioned r0 holds the index into the array of structs, so we multiply by 32, the shift left instruction doesnt care that this is an index or that a shift of 5 has something to do with structs it is just bits fed into the alu causing bits to shift out one side and zeros to shift in the other side.  Some cpus will take the last bit shifted out into the carry bit, not as a carry bit but as a place holder for cascaded shifts, likewise the zflag might be computed and the n flag (sign bit) just in case you consider this to be a twos complement number (after shifting), or want some shortcuts in programming.  But those are just bits to the cpu, no meaning.

At this point we as humans think of r2 as holding an offset into memory for the index into the array of structs but to the cpu its just bits.  We perform the add. we consider one operand to be an address and the other an offset, but to the cpu they are just bits being operated on.  Add's normally dont care about signed vs unsigned, the beauty of twos complement is you can feed unsigned and signed into the same adder logic, which often computes the carry out flag (unsigned overflow) and the v flag (signed overflow) plus the z flag, zero and n flag negative result, all in one shot, none if which have any meaning to the add, just computed like the result in case you want to use the flags for something.  In this case the cpu has no way of knowing we are computing an address.

And now we define bits in a register as an address and perform a load.  But are only considered by the cpu to be an address for that one instruction, that one moment in time, that register just moments before were some bits that were the result of an add operation.

What are we reading from memory?  more bits, not a floating point value, just 32 bits.  Now some cpus might have a direct way to do a load from memory directly into a floating point register,  some cpus dont have floating point and it is all synthesized with general purpose registers.  Even ones with floating point might use gprs for floating point values, if for example the code above was doing this:

```
mystruct[j].f=mystruct[i].f;
```

You probably wouldnt want to burn an fpu register if you could, you might use a gpr as I have below.  If there were no actual floating point math near this code, it is just bits being moved from one place to another, no reason to get the fpu involved.

The above line of code might look like this when all said and done:

```
ldr r1,mystruct_base
shl r2,r0,#5
add r2,r2,r1
ldr r0,[r2]
shl r2,r3,#5
add r2,r2,r1
str r0,[r2]
```

where r0 is i when this code is entered and r3 is j.  The cpu doesnt know or care what the bits are with a few exceptions.  for the ldr and str r2 is for the instruction time period considered an address in memory to something.  other than that there is no structures or floating point or signed or unsigned integers.  Nothing.  Just bits.

Yes, usually when someone says 32-bit computer they mean 32 bit registers.  That is a good generalization, often the bit size also the address size of the memory bus, 32 bit meaning you can address in theory 32 bits worth of memory, 4GBytes.  That gets a bit fuzzy though as you may know from the x86 or others.  Often, esp with x86 you will see a 64 bit processor operated in a 32 bit mode, basically running code/instructions that expect 32 bit registers not 64 bit, with x86 the "registers" have different ways to access them as 8, 16, 32, or 63 bit, so you can play these games.

All of these questions you ask and more are answered in the assembly language for a processor.  Now mips unfortunately goes out of its way to confuse you, and x86 does as well, so avoid those, pick something simple like the msp430 or ARM or ARM in thumb mode to learn first.

Comment: tl;dr, but +1 for the yeoman effort and for remembering to cite Uncle Edsgar.